# if var equals liquid value then

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is: if variable equals a value pulled from shopify settings then it appends one piece of code, and if not-another.

jQuery does work with shopify liquid. I've tried appending these codes without if statement. Works perfectly. Looks like I made a syntax mistake somewhere, but can't figure out where. Can some one point me to it plz?

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $bgset = {{settings.k_h}};
                  if ($bgset == color) {
                  $('head').append('<style>html,body {background-color:{{settings.shop_bg_color}};}</style>');
}
else {
  $('head').append('<style>html,body {background-image:url({{ 'mainbg.jpg' | asset_url }});}</style>');}

});
```

Comment: So where are you getting `color` from, and what's it suppose to be ?

Comment: Try `var bgset = "{{settings.kakogo_huja}}";`

Comment: color comes from {{settings.k_h}}

Comment: So does `$bgset`, and what's with the dollarsign? Is it a string then, if so you need quotes  etc. Open the console and check for errors.

Comment: nope. var bgset = "{{settings.kakogo_huja}}"; not working

Comment: adeneo, thanks for extended explanation. working fine. tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to compare $bgset to see if it equals the string 'color'. That would mean both 'color' and $bgset need to be quoted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $bgset = '{{settings.k_h}}';
   if ($bgset == 'color') {
       $('head').append('<style>html,body {background-color:{{settings.shop_bg_color}};}</style>');
   } else {
       $('head').append("<style>html,body {background-image:url({{ 'mainbg.jpg' | asset_url }});}</style>");}
});
```